# Request truncated for large String body in Spring boot rest service

Tags: spring-boot, truncation

I have a Spring boot 2.1.6 rest service(POST) that is defined to accept String (text/plain) as the request body. The service is expecting the body as a valid JSON. When I ran load test for this service, 1% of the requests were failing. It was later found that the failures were happening when the requests body is not a valid json. Even though I was using the same request body for all the requests, some of them were failing. From the logs I could find that, for all the failed transactions, the requests were truncated before it reached the controller method. In some cases the body was empty. 
What could be causing this? Could there be any server level parameters to accept certain size of the input body? My request body is around 200 KB.

Comment: Could you please provide more information like the endpoint and the sample json that you are sending. Also , there is `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size` which could be set to decide the max request size which by default is 10MB.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the exact json. It has around 4K elements and 200KB of size. I am not setting the max-requests-size, so I assume it goes with the default value which is much greater than what I want. I can still try setting this value explicitly.